# How to judge whether the SQL update statement to delete success

Tags: php, mysql

I use the code to update data in mysql.But it always echo "sucess " whatever $id equal to any integer.

```
$id=isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']+0:0;
$sql="update user set age=50 where id=".$id;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if($result)
    echo "update sucess<br />";
else
    echo "update failed";
```

Comment: Use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mysql_affected_rows()` instead.

So that an you'll know that it made changes you want.

Obligatory note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Here's what it will look like in using mysqli:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = 'UPDATE user SET age = 50 WHERE id = ?';
    $update = $con->prepare($sql);
    $update->bind_param('i', $id);
    $update->execute();

    if($update->affected_rows > 0) {
        echo 'updated';
    } else {
        echo 'nothing';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice layout ;) - and I love the *"Here's what it will look like in using mysqli:"* - Now if only Stack would have something like SQLfiddle.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, i wish they would include a php and sql feature also in the stack snippet :D

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually that deprecation template is from Second Rikudo's answer. bookmarked it also :D http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860140/3859027

Comment: I meant as a "general" layout, the looks of it. I think it's my graphical side talking lol